# Is it possible in firebase auth to update user and custom claims at the same time node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

Is it possible to update a user and the custom claims at the same time?

I can update the custom claims via the example in docs

```
admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(uid, {admin: true}).then(() => {
});
```

I can update the user with

```
firebase.auth().updateUser(request.body.user.uid, {
   displayName:   request.body.user.username,
   email:   request.body.user.email
})
```

I thought it would be as simple as this example below but it keeps leaving the custom claims as undefined

```
const customClaims = {
  admin: true,
  accessLevel: 9
};

firebase.auth().updateUser(request.body.user.uid, {
  displayName:   request.body.user.username,
  email:   request.body.user.email,
  customClaims: customClaims
})
```

Is there a way to do both at the same time? Or do they have to be separate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [updateUser](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth) method is documented to take a string uid and an [UpdateRequest](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.UpdateRequest) object.  As you can see from the linked API docs, UpdateRequest doesn't have a customClaims property, or anything that lets you update the claims in the same call.  You can always [file a feature request](http://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features) if this is important to your use case.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: This is supported in other languages -- Java, Python and Go. Node.js API is a little behind in this regard.